# Send email without leaving a copy in the Sent folder outlook c#

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices

When i am sending mail through outlook in c# ,all the mails are saved in sent box. Is there any way which does not leave the copy of mail in sent folder programatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `MailItem.DeleteAfterSubmit` property to true before calling `Send`.

Comment: Thanks it works, but I'm sending mails through Exchange Server as well. This is an optional requirement. Not sure how to do it through exchange

Comment: MailItem.DeleteAfterSubmit will work under both Exchange or any other transport, such as SMTP.

Comment: Thanks.. but i am sending by creating object of EmailMessage. So Email message has no such property. Is there any method to avoid saving of sent mail.

Comment: What is EmailMessage? There is no such object in the Outlook Object Model.

Comment: I am sending like this :ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);

service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password", "MYDOMAIN");
service.Url = new Uri("https://exchangebox/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

EmailMessage em = new EmailMessage(service);
em.Subject = "example email";
em.Body = new MessageBody("hello world");
em.Sender = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailAddress("john.smith@example.com");
em.ToRecipients.Add(("bob.smith@example.com"));

// Send the email and put it into the SentItems:
em.Send();

Comment: The above method is used to send mail through exchange , in this case email is saving in send box

Comment: Can't help you with EWS, sorry, I assumed you are using the Outlook Object Model Please tag your question appropriately.